# React Native Timeline ListView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net-core, react-router, components

I'm trying to achieve a timeline in my .Net Core React app.

This is my timeline.js code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Timeline from 'react-native-timeline-listview';

constructor(){
    super()
    this.data = [
      {time: '09:00', title: 'Event 1', description: 'Event 1 Description'},
      {time: '10:45', title: 'Event 2', description: 'Event 2 Description'},
      {time: '12:00', title: 'Event 3', description: 'Event 3 Description'},
      {time: '14:00', title: 'Event 4', description: 'Event 4 Description'},
      {time: '16:30', title: 'Event 5', description: 'Event 5 Description'}
    ]
  }

render(){
    return(
        <Timeline
          data={this.data}
        />
    )
}

export default connect()(Timeline);
```

This what my App.js looks like :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Timeline from './components/Timeline';
...
...
 return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    {templates}
                </header>
                <Layout>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/timeline' component={Timeline} />
                </Layout>

            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I'm getting Unexpected token, expected at "constructor(){" ..How to fix this, should I create a timeline class that extends from React Component ?

After I added the class which extends from React, I get an error "Module parse failed: Unexpected token" in the Index.js :

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const initialState = window.initialReduxState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement);

registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Could you include your entire first component? There are a couple of syntax errors and the `class` is missing.

Comment: @Tholle Which component exactly you want me to include ? and what are the syntax errors you mentioned ? (I included the whole react timeline component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `constructor` and `render` method must be part of a class that extends `React.Component` in order to make it a proper React component.

**Example**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.data = [
      { time: "09:00", title: "Event 1", description: "Event 1 Description" },
      { time: "10:45", title: "Event 2", description: "Event 2 Description" },
      { time: "12:00", title: "Event 3", description: "Event 3 Description" },
      { time: "14:00", title: "Event 4", description: "Event 4 Description" },
      { time: "16:30", title: "Event 5", description: "Event 5 Description" }
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return <Timeline data={this.data} />;
  }
}

export default connect()(MyComponent);
```

Comment: After I made the changes you recommended I'm getting an error in the Index.js : node_modules/react-native-timeline-listview/lib/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (62:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render() {
|     return (
|       <View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>
|         <ListView
|           ref="listView"

Comment: @AyoubSalhi What token does it complain about exactly?